# C++ Experiment: How can I improve this class?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Define or Implement C# Property in ISO C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742740/how-to-define-or-implement-c-sharp-property-in-iso-c)

I was experimenting with writing a class that would simulate C# properties in C++, and I came up with the code below. It works great for POD types (although the declaration syntax is of course not nearly as terse as C#), but I can't think of a way to have the getter return something other than the stored object type (likewise, the setter must take exactly the stored type). I would like to be able to specify a getter that returns a (possibly const) reference, rather than a copy. And of course, I want to use template magic to deduce this at compile time, rather than having a separate class for each permutation.

```
template<typename owner, typename propertyType, propertyType (owner::*getter)() const, void (owner::*setter)(propertyType)>
class property
{
    friend class property<owner, propertyType, getter, nullptr>;

private:
    owner &mOwner;

public:
    property(owner &owner)
        : mOwner(owner)
    {
    }

    template<typename otherProperty>
    property(const otherProperty &other)
        : mOwner(other.mOwner)
    {
    }

    property &operator=(const property &other)
    {
        assert(setter);
        (mOwner.*setter)((other.*)getter());
        return *this;
    }

    property &operator=(propertyType value)
    {
        assert(setter);
        (mOwner.*setter)(value);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename otherProperty>
    property &operator=(const otherProperty &other)
    {
        assert(setter);
        (mOwner.*setter)(other);
        return *this;
    }

    operator propertyType() const
    {
        assert(getter);
        return (mOwner.*getter)();
    }
};

class Test
{
    typedef std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4> array_type;
private:
    int mId;
    array_type mArray;

    int GetId() const;
    void SetId(int newId);

    // I would rather return a reference here, not a copy
    array_type GetArray() const;

public:
    property<Test, int, &GetId, &SetId> Id;
    property<Test, int, &GetId, nullptr> ReadOnlyId;

    // if GetArray returned a reference, this line would fail to compile
    property<Test, array_type, &GetArray, nullptr> Array;

public:
    Test()
        : mId(0)
        , Id(*this)
        , ReadOnlyId(Id)
        , Array(*this)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Why put work in codifying an antipattern like getter/setter?

Comment: @Kerrek Good point but it’s still interesting to see how this can be emulated.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It reminds me of that film *[The Wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wave_(2008_film))* -- it was still interesting to see if it could be done! :-)

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend writing C# code in the C++ language. Instead prefer idiomatic C++.

Comment: Isn't there another problem with this? The getter is invoked by converting the property to the required type. This will happen implicitly in an assignment or passing as a parameter, e.g.  `foo(test.ReadOnlyId)` where `foo` accepts an `int`. But what if the property is an object with further properties? In C# you can conveniently traverse a graph of objects (potentially violating the Law of Demiter) with expressions like `obj.A.B.C.D`  but instead you'd have to provider a `.get` memfunc in `property`, resulting in `obj.A.get().B.get().C.get().D`.

Comment: And to solve this would require the ability to overload `operator.` which was never thought a good idea. I think this is discussed in D&EC++

Comment: This question would be a better fit for the new code review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kerrek: It's just a thought experiment. I'm working exclusively in C# right now, and occasionally I pick C++ (or Python or whatever) experiments to keep my skills sharp.

Comment: @mos: Sure, fair enough. I look forward to the answer, too!

Comment: @KerrekSB Why would you call that an "anti-pattern" (whatever that means)? Sure, it's not idiomatic in C++ so you probably shouldn't do it, but I'd like the language to offer this feature.

Comment: @PaulManta: Having getters and setters is a strong indicator that your class isn't expressing the correct domain of responsibility. It's not a watertight condition, of course, but it raises a couple of eyebrows.

Comment: @KerrekSB What's "expressing the correct domain of responsibility" supposed to mean?

Comment: @PaulManta: In C++, classes are supposed to represent an idea, and in simple terms, getters and setters mean you got the wrong idea. This is somewhat different in C# and Java, where you're forced by decree to shoehorn *everything* into a class, and so there are situations where getters and setters appeal. In some way C++ allows you a wider set of tools, so getters/setters are not really needed.

Comment: @KerrekSB We agree on that it should represent an idea, but saying getters and setters are an 'anti-pattern' is going way too far. Just a simple example: `std::vector::size` is pretty much a getter. Just because there are people who make getters and setters for every single member variable, that doesn't mean it should be generally discouraged. Any technique is misused.

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question. Really, I didn't care about "how do I write C# properties in C++", what I wanted was how to get the getter/setter templates (in this instance) to accept a wider variety of function signatures". I'll ask a new question.